# How to iterate through a dictionary if every key has a List as a Value

Tags: dictionary, generics, binary-tree

```
public void createList(Node root)
    {

        Dictionary<int, LinkedList<Node>> track = new Dictionary<int, LinkedList<Node>>();
        LinkedList<Node> first = new LinkedList<Node>();
        first.AddFirst(root);
        track.Add(1, first);

        int level = 1;
        LinkedList<Node> temp = new LinkedList<Node>();
        while (true)
        {
            LinkedList<Node> lis = new LinkedList<Node>();
            if (level == 1)
                temp = first;
            foreach (Node n in temp)
            {
                if (n.left!=null)
                    lis.AddLast(n.left);
                if (n.right != null)
                    lis.AddLast(n.right);

            }
            level++;
            temp=lis;
            if (lis.Count > 0)
            {
                track.Add(level, lis);
            }
            else
                break;

        }

    }
```

Hello, in the above program in **C#** i am adding each level of a Binary tree to separate Linked Lists and then adding every linked list to a dictionary. Can some one please tell me how to iterate the through each linked list in the dictionary? If i have Track<1,<1,2,3,4>>, how do i get to 1,2,3,4? What if I wanted to add to or delete to 1,2,3,4?

Thanks to Ramhound for pointers on the problem, I guess i will have to get the LinkedList object for each key in the Dictionary and then modify the linked list, how do i make sure the change reflects back in the Dictionary is my next question=> Please let me know if the following makes sense

LinkedListObject= Dictionary[mykey];
//Modify the LL, Add,delete etc
myDictionary[myKey] = LinkedListObject; //put it back

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through the linked lists, get a list of values form the Dictionary.

To get the first linked list just call `get(1)` on the dicitionary and it will return a `LinkedList<Node>`.

Note, I assume this is test code as this has several problems that would keep it from compiling.

Comment: It actually is C# and even then it still has problems.

Comment: I always assume anything that uses `Dictionary` is C#, as Java replaced the `Dictionary` interface with the `Map` interface ages ago.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can modify the dictionary while looping through it.  You would have to keep track of what keys you are going to remove, loop through THAT collection, and remove each key at a time.

There are alternatives to a Dictionary that would allow you to modify it while looping through the contents.

Comment: The code compiles fine in c#, but i still cannot figure out how to loop through a linked list for each key of the dictionary, is there an example i can refer to? I dont want to remove the key but a value from the LIST for every key in the DICT..

Comment: @Witty - I will again point out that you cannot modify the dictionary while looping through the contents.  You would have to keep track of what you want to modify, then outside of the loop, do exactly that.